# How to insert Blob column in Oracle with Non-Ascii characters in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, blob

I am trying to Insert/Update data into BLOB Column where there are few Non-Ascii Characters present. When I retrieve the column values, they are not fetched as same as when I inserted them.

// This is sample data or data snippet of very large data text where i see the difference after update.

Tried this updated Query:

UPDATE   Blob_table 
SET FILE_BLOB = utl_raw.cast_to_raw('00001Ý#01¨ return') 
where eid = 1;

When i fetch the table:

SELECT FILE_BLOb FROM  Blob_table WHERE eid = 1;

Above Query output: 00001Ã�#01Â¨ return

**Expected :** 00001Ý#01¨ return

**Actual   :** 00001Ã�#01Â¨ return

*Can anyone explain Why the data is retrieved wrongly and how to fix them?*

**Oracle Database Version :**

"Oracle Database 18c Enterprise Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.5.0.0.0"

**Character Set Details:**

NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET -    AL16UTF16

NLS_CHARACTERSET    - AL32UTF8

Comment: This is generally problem of character set. Which tool do you use to fetch the data?

Comment: SQL Developer 4.2.0.16.356

Comment: Why do you use `BLOB` rather than `CLOB`? Character set AL32UTF8 supports any character, so converting to BLOB seems to be pointless to me.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But this table is already existing table and Users want it that way.
We see some special characters coming into this table. So Want to know why those Original characters get changed and is there any way we can fix them with the BLOB column itself. 
Otherwise (No other option) we have to recommend to Users to have CLOB column.

Comment: In case of BLOB, user upload file in SQL Developer: https://it.toolbox.com/blogs/loannismoutsatsos/load-images-and-other-blobs-with-sql-developer-042210

Comment: `RAW` is limited to 2000 Bytes, so "very large data text" would be little exaggerated.

Comment: The BLOB Data is getting inserted via TIBCO. String length (in BLOB Column) is usually > 40000 Characters .
Just to try out them from local (sql Dev) i tried the UTL_RAW function to mock the data issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BLOB` holds binary data, so the expected output should be something like `3030303031C39D233031C2A82072657475726E`.

If you expect `00001Ý#01¨ return` then you need to convert binary data back to character data, apparently your tool does it implicitly. Using [CAST_TO_VARCHAR2](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_raw.htm#ARPLS71386) should return correct result.

`CAST_TO_VARCHAR2` uses the current database character set (AL32UTF8 in your case). If your client uses a different character set, then you have to use [DBMS_LOB.CONVERTTOCLOB](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_lob.htm#ARPLS602), there you can specify it.

However, the simplest way would be to convert your column to proper data type `CLOB`, this will make your life much easier.